# How to chop command line when using Exec from MsBuild

Tags: msbuild

In my build, I want to feed a list of source files to clang-format. I'm doing this in MsBuild. I find the list of files in an ItemGroup which can be quite large. I can format the command line like this:

```
$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)clang-format.exe -style=file -output-replacements-xml %(ClangFilesToFormat.Identity)
```

However, I think I'm exceeding the max command line length and the command fails. So, I'd like to call clang-format in batches of X files. I don't want to call it for each individual file because it's just way too slow if I do that.

How can I split an ItemGroup into batches of X items, or otherwise solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without the context it is hard to tell, but I would expect the syntax `%(ClangFilesToFormat.Identity)` to cause batching (so, calling the command for each individual file). Assuming `clang-format.exe` expects the files to be space-delimited, I think you would want to use `@(ClangFilesToFormat, ' ')` instead. Consider first using a diagnostic line such as the following to verify that you are getting the string you want.

```
<Error Text="ClangFilesToFormat: @(ClangFilesToFormat, ' ')" />
```